# в одном компоненте несколько условия для отображения vue.js, vue.cli

Tags: vue.js

День добрый! Вопрос следующий: можно ли в одном компоненте применить к разным блокам несколько условий отображения v-if, v-else, которые НЕ будут зависеть друг от друга попарно. Отдельно v-iv/v-else для отображения хедера двух видов, допустим, и отдельно v-if/v-else в этом же компоненте для отображения каких-либо других блоков.

Comment: в оф.документации есть такая информация: "Но что если мы хотим управлять отображением сразу нескольких элементов? В таком случае можно применить v-if к псевдоэлементу <template>, который служит невидимой обёрткой и сам в результатах отрисовки не появляется.". То  есть, я в теге template внутри тега template прописываю условия для второго случая? Не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите использовать v-if и v-else несколько раз в своей верстке внутри одного компонента, то можно использовать просто v-if следующим образом

```js
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        a: true,
        b: false
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <span v-if="a">
      a
    </span>
    <span v-if="!a">
      not a
    </span>
     <span v-if="b">
      b
    </span>
    <span v-if="!b">
      not b
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```